# How can I get this Excel VBA to run for all rows, instead of just the first row?

Tags: excel, vba

So darn new to VBA, almost got this working.  I'm trying to reset some Data Validation lists so that if someone changes a Country selection, then a couple of cells will reset.  Example, if I pick USA then I want the corresponding State and Shift column to display "Please select..." and if the user changes the country to something other than USA then it doesn't say anything in the State column, only in the Shift column.  I got this working but it only runs for the first row.  I'm not sure if my range is wrong or if I'm supposed to loop, both of which I'm totally ignorant on.

```
Option Explicit

'The way this works is if the Payroll Country changes then the sub selections
'of State and Shift should reset based on if the country is USA

'Payroll Country = A column
'State = X column
'Shift = Y column

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    '"If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub" is the VBA code to prevent an error if user highlights the range and deletes the data
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub


            If Target.Address = "$A$6" And Target.Value = "USA" Then
                Range("X6").Value = "Please select..."
                Range("Z6").Value = "Please select..."
       
            ElseIf Target.Address = "$A$6" And Target.Value <> "USA" Then
                Range("X6").Value = ""
                Range("Z6").Value = "Please select..."
        
            End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What range should it run on?  Do you want it to react to changes in ColA from row6 and below?

Comment: Thank you, yes the range should be from ColA and from row6 down, correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'CountLarge handles larger ranges...
    'check Target column and row...
    If Target.Column = 1 and Target.Row >= 6 Then 
        With Target.EntireRow
            .Columns("X").Value = IIf(Target.Value = "USA", _
                                     "Please select...", "")
            .Columns("Z").Value = "Please select..."
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the CountLarge knowledge!  I tried this but it still behaves the same, only works on Row 6.

Comment: Works for me on all rows 6 and greater

Comment: You are AWESOME! Thank you!  I removed the Option Explicit at the top and it worked.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change

- If you out-comment the line `Application.EnableEvents = False` you will notice that there will be more `Debug.Print` lines (one more for `USA`, two more for `non-USA`) i.e. after writing (`crg.Value = InitialString`), the code calls itself (actually the worksheet change event calls the `InitializeCountry` procedure) again but 'luckily' exits after the line `If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` since it is writing to a non-intersecting range, but nevertheless debug-printing the `Source Range Address` once more, before it continues with the line `Debug.Print "Criteria Range (Both Columns): " & crg.Address(0, 0)`. This should help you to fully understand why the disabling of events is necessary.
- Out-comment or delete the range addresses related `Debug.Print` lines when done testing because they're slowing down the code.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    InitializeCountry Target
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub InitializeCountry( _
        ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Declare constants.
    
    Const SourceFirstCellAddress As String = "A6"
    Const StateColumn As String = "X"
    Const ShiftColumn As String = "Z"
    Const CriteriaString As String = "USA"
    Const InitialString As String = "Please select..."
    
    ' Read.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = ws.Range(SourceFirstCellAddress)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sfCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1)
    Debug.Print "Source Range Address:          " & srg.Address(0, 0)
        
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(srg, Target) ' Intersect Range
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print "Intersect Range Address:       " & irg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' ShiftColumn
    Dim crg As Range ' Criteria Range
    Set crg = irg.EntireRow.Columns(ShiftColumn)
    Debug.Print "Criteria Range (ShiftColumn):  " & crg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' StateColumn
    Dim erg As Range ' Empty Range
    Dim iCell As Range ' Current Intersect Cell
    For Each iCell In irg.Cells
        If iCell.Value = CriteriaString Then
            Set crg = Union(crg, iCell.EntireRow.Columns(StateColumn))
        Else
            If erg Is Nothing Then
                Set erg = iCell.EntireRow.Columns(StateColumn)
            Else
                Set erg = Union(erg, iCell.EntireRow.Columns(StateColumn))
            End If
        End If
    Next iCell
    
    ' Write.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' This is crucial to not retrigger the event procedure when writing!
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    crg.Value = InitialString
    Debug.Print "Criteria Range (Both Columns): " & crg.Address(0, 0)
    
    If Not erg Is Nothing Then
        erg.ClearContents ' erg.Value = Empty
        Debug.Print "Empty Range (StateColumn):     " & erg.Address(0, 0)
    End If
    
SafeExit:

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
    
ClearError:
    ' Don't uncomment this line!
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub


' Test multi-range (only possible with VBA).
Sub InitializeCountryTEST()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A6:A20,A31:A50,A61:A100")
    rg.Value = "USA"
End Sub

' Debug.Print result for 'USA' (no 'Empty Range'):
'Source Range Address:          A6:A1048576
'Intersect Range Address:       A6:A20,A31:A50,A61:A100
'Criteria Range(ShiftColumn):   Z6:Z20
'Criteria Range (Both Columns): Z6:Z20,X6:X20,X31:X50,X61:X100

' Debug.Print result otherwise:
'Source Range Address:          A6:A1048576
'Intersect Range Address:       A6:A20,A31:A50,A61:A100
'Criteria Range(ShiftColumn):   Z6:Z20
'Criteria Range (Both Columns): Z6:Z20
'Empty Range (StateColumn):     X6:X20,X31:X50,X61:X100
```